# Windsor Container and internal properties

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Is there any solution how to initialize properties of component marked as 'internal'? What assembly name should I use for InternalsVisibleTo attrribute or it won't help?

Answer (score 1):

internal means that they are only accessible to code within the same assembly.

That said, you can use reflector to rip the assembly back into the original code, change access modifier to be public, then compile it back down.

Unless the assembly is obfuscated; at which point you're kind of SOL.